# jquery data table, passing large json string

Tags: javascript, c#, datatables, large-data

I have a jQuery data table and use ajax call to populate it. Data in a C# datatable is converted to JSOn string in a web method API and the result is passed to data table. It works fine when I have a couple of thousand rows of data but if I have something like 100,000 rows I get out of memory error. I looked around for this issue and tried to implement some of the suggestions but it didn't work. I don't believe I have circular reference because (I guess) in that case even the one with smaller data would fail. Here is what I have (so far), where in response to a submit button click, data table is populated:

```
var tblFacCert = $("#tblFacCert").DataTable({
    jQueryUI: true,
    data: [],
    dom: 'lfrtip',
    processing: true,
    stateSave: true,
    ....
});

$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function (event) {
    var facCertUrl = "../services/easg.asmx/GetComplianceReportData";
    var facCertParams = "{ 'startDate': '" + $("#tbStartDate").val() + "', 'certID': '" + $('#ddlCertificate').val() + "'}";
    populteTable(facCertUrl, facCertParams, tblFacCert);
})

function populteTable(ws_url, parameters, table) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ws_url,
        cache: false,
        data: parameters,
    }).done(function (result) {
        table.clear().draw();
        table.processing = true;
        jResult = JSON.parse(result.d);
        table.rows.add(jResult).draw();
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown); <--- Here I can see the following error thrown
    });
}
// Error: 
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
StackTrace: 
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString() 
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, 
SerializationFormat serializationFormat) 
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams) 
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)
ExceptionType:System.OutOfMemoryException


[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public string GetComplianceReportData(string startDate, string certID)
{
    DateTime dtStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
    int iCertItemID = int.Parse(certID);
    DataTable dt = FacCompliance.GetFacCompliances(dtStartDate, iCertItemID);
    string JSONresult;
    JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

    /* I tried this, as was suggested in a post, no luck */

    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

    //using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    //{
    //    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    //    serializer.Serialize(writer, dt);
    //}

    return JSONresult;
}
```

another suggestion, web.config change:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        ....
        <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="500000"/>
    </appSettings>

<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

I also tried adding "serevrSide: true" to data tale initialization but get this error if I do so:

```
"Unhandled exception at line 36, column 442 in https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'data' of undefined or null reference"
```

Comment: You're getting an `OutOfMemoryException` while calling `StringBuilder
.ToString` - it looks like it's a huge string you're trying to serialize, can you let us know what `StringBuilder.Length` is?

Comment: Basically, the amount of memory a string occupies in memory is 20 + 2* length bytes, so you can calculate the max length you can have on your box

Comment: 34,867,955. One thing interesting is that when I run this on my local machine, pointing to the same database and getting the same data, same SB length, it works. When it is deployed to server, same data chokes. Could this be related to some IIS setting? It is Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5.

Comment: you could split the result and retrieve it using Ajax

Comment: @derloopkat can you give me a sample code on how to do it?

Comment: I noticed the table data gets displayed if I recycle application pool. How could application pool cause running out of memory error?

Comment: If you have a *memory* leak, your w3wp process will consume more and more memory over time. That is actually a great lead to what might be wrong. Can you use *Task Manager* or *perfmon* to measure memory consumption of your w3wp process over time? 
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-use-perfmon-performance-monitor-windows

Comment: @ironstone13 thanks, I will give it a try and see if there is a leak. Would the fact that application pool recycle, at least temporarily, fixes the issue a hint at memory leak?